# Graphs from Seifert surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, knot-theory

Given a Seifert surface if we make the disks and bands infinitely small and thin it becomes a graph where the disks are vertices and the bands are edges. Can we say that following theorem,

> *For every Seifert surface there is an unique graph and vice versa.*

is trivial?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that twisting a region to get more bigons doesn't change the graph but gives you a seifert surface that is not ambient-isotopic to the original surface.